# NodeJS equivalent to Java's ElasticSearch/Lucene `QueryParser.escape()` method

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, lucene

Is the following method available in the NodeJS version of ElasticSearch or Lucene client?

```
org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser.escape()
```

I would like to escape the characters (provided by the user) to be inserted in a `query_string`.

Comment: Hmm, since Lucene will do it eventually, why do you want/need to do it when sending the query string? You can safely send your query string in the JS client and Lucene will properly escape the characters when it runs the query.

Comment: The query does fail when it contains accents, e.g, "é"

Comment: Yes, but for that you can use a custom analyzer with an [`asciifolding` token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-asciifolding-tokenfilter.html)